# Haskell Multiple Function Composition

Tags: filter, composition

Im trying to understand function composition in Haskell.

According to ZVON http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/filter_f.html
the filter function should have two arguments, a bool function and a list.

Example `filter (>5) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` returns anything greater than 5:
`[6,7,8]`

Question, how does the following line with several function compositions pass in a boolean for the filter to utilize?

`map fst . filter snd . assocs . soeA`

shouldn't it be map fst . filter (==True) snd . assocs . soeA

To analyze I run the first two functions of the composition and pass an argument: `assocs . soeA $ 9` returns
`[(0,False),(1,False),(2,True),(3,True),(4,False),(5,True),(6,False),(7,True),(8,False),(9,False)]`

`soe 9` returns `[2,3,5,7]`

Somehow the bool value in each array element of soeA is being used, but any help explaining how this composition is working would be very much appreciated.

Full Code is:
`

```
module FastSeive where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed



soeST :: forall s. Int -> ST s (STUArray s Int Bool)
soeST n = do
    arr <- newArray (0, n) True
    mapM_ (\i -> writeArray arr i False) [0, 1]
    let n2 = n `div` 2

    let loop :: Int -> ST s ()
        loop i | i > n2 = return ()
        loop i = do
            b <- readArray arr i

            let reset :: Int -> ST s ()
                reset j | j > n = return ()
                reset j = writeArray arr j False >> reset (j + i)

            when b (reset (2*i))

            loop (succ i)

    loop 2
    return arr


soeA :: Int -> UArray Int Bool
soeA n = runST (soeST n >>= freeze)


soe :: Int -> [Int]
soe = map fst . filter snd . assocs . soeA


soeCount :: Int -> Int
soeCount = length . filter id . elems . soeA
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: here, `snd` is the `Bool`-returning function `filter` expects. In the expression you wrote: `map fst . filter (==True) snd . assocs . soeA`. `snd` would be `filter`'s second argument, while `(==True)` would be the first one. Of course, it won't typecheck because `filter` is already applied to two arguments, and cannot be used in function composition: it's not a function anymore.

---

For a longer answer, we can actually apply `(.)`'s definition to find out what's happening:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
-- In haskell, it is defined as being right associative

-- Meaning that if we put explicit parenthesises, we'd have:
soe = (map fst . (filter snd . (assocs . soeA)))
-- That only really matters for the compiler, though,
-- because we know function composition is associative.

soe = map fst . filter snd . assocs . soeA
-- "Un-pointfree-ing" it:
soe x = (map fst . filter snd . assocs . soeA) x
-- Applying (.)'s definition:
soe x = map fst ((filter snd . assocs . soeA) x)
-- Again:
soe x = map fst (filter snd ((assocs . soeA) x))
-- And again:
soe x = map fst (filter snd (asocs (soeA x)))
```

It's now clear that `snd` is `filter`'s first argument, while the second argument will evaluate to what `assocs (soeA x)` will evaluate to.

More generally, when one writes `f . g . h`, this can be read right-to-left as a function that first applies `h` to its argument, then `g` to the result, then `f` to the next result, and yields that final value.

---

Now, for the even longer answer, we can look at how the types for your expression will be inferred. It'll tell us why `snd` is the `Bool`-returning function `filter` expects even though it has a type signature of `snd :: (a, b) -> b`.

Disclaimer: I don't have a background in compiler engineering; the terms I'll be using may be inexact.

The type of `filter` is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. The type of `snd` is `(a, b) -> b`.

Those are actually parameterized types. We can make the type parameters explicit:

```
filter :: forall a.   (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
snd    :: forall a b. (a, b) -> b
```

We'll also rename `filter`'s type argument in order to make it non-ambiguous in what we'll write next:

```
filter :: forall c. (c -> Bool) -> [c] -> [c]
```

`filter` gets applied first to `snd`. So, we can try and unify `c -> Bool` from `filter` with `(a, b) -> b`, `snd`'s type. We get these equations :

```
c -> Bool = (a, b) -> b

===

c = (a, b)
b = Bool

===

c = (a, Bool)
b = Bool
```

We'll assume that `assocs (soeA x)`'s type is `[(Int, Bool)]`. Since `filter`'s second argument has the type `[c]`, we can unify further:

```
[c] = [(Int, Bool)]

===

c = (Int, Bool)
```

This also gives us:

```
(Int, Bool) = c = (a, Bool)

===

a = Int
```

So, after type application, we get these concrete types for our sub-expressions :

```
filter :: ((Int, Bool) -> Bool) -> [(Int, Bool)] -> [(Int, Bool)]
snd    ::  (Int, Bool) -> Bool
```

Well, of course, we could have used GHC's type inference all along to tell us about that, either using GHCi, or through a text editor's haskell plugin.

Comment: Thanks. your sample with the parenthesis "soe x = map fst (filter snd ((assocs . soeA) x))"  really helped clarify